# Vega lite: having two separate datasets with separate filters

Tags: vega-lite

I was wondering how I could have a sort of hconcat in vega lite, but with two separate datasets. I want to have the top 10 and lower 10 values displayed next to each other with different constraints but I am having issues with the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data and transforms can be specified at any level of the chart, and they are passed down to subcharts when applicable. Here is an example adapted from [Filtering Top K Items](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/window_top_k.html) in the example gallery, which applies a different filter to each concatenated chart ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMJMfPtIQHbxmQCCkANFMQMYB7AE6EyARgAMkgL7cq1WvUYs2qSACEefIaLIBWAGxyFGJQyat2AYW11dY1AA4nJ6jToXV7ACJ2BIo5ghvpu7uYqVuoAov4OZAAsofLuaJ6RalAAYnGBZABMAMxhiumWmZAA4rl6qIbGKeFl3uoAEjVBhgDsJWbNUVAAkh0SxY2lyuXsAFIjqOL5vR6TLVAA0nNg+rLjfSsDkAAym12uu8teBwCym-VLafsVAHKbhTumFxnsAPKbAJw9c4PS4VAAKJ2SH2BX3UAEVNvkEvcIlN1AAlTYJRZAlGrSAAZRODShuIOABUTmcSf0KgBVBHiZE09gANUxxlMAF0qGFIPBhLBmMQAGYiAC2ZEoiihkAA7gBLZjQQSyyW0QQAB3YAuYAGs7LBSOodfqZJygXQRJlyLRhfLCLhoOwAnpeJARExhOwmAIWNBFQBzSBm0wyKjmqjYITMfgISWmdDuPk6kXitWQO24eCEL3qOAMMUAOhNYAAPABeMCFYMR1KQMWwYT69QAI0bPBlLCE-uYQdQibrAA8yLb7Y7nfE3fAAJ4aoKQACO+EF8HliFXWDE90w05HUOoGbHTvUjw7qQPM7n7GYgjFirwZ-PmGIVpHh4dx50eTdmvYsE3AoBmIP7CJ63okPwfqBsG+5gGGqTwRgvQDhgyaCqmwgSqgNqHlmObegg+BFiWAB8YDiH8NYWg2TbsG2XoWl2gg9n2aCwZAw79u+44npOUCXvOS4rmuCDypuwZAjue5Ppgdofs6IKPk+fKzvON53swD6SahL7CJko7ybx35QL+6j-jmsBAXYHr4XmEFQb2MFPoh1AuXB4YgDIQA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"student": "A", "score": 100},
      {"student": "B", "score": 56},
      {"student": "C", "score": 88},
      {"student": "D", "score": 65},
      {"student": "E", "score": 45},
      {"student": "F", "score": 23},
      {"student": "G", "score": 66},
      {"student": "H", "score": 67},
      {"student": "I", "score": 13},
      {"student": "J", "score": 12},
      {"student": "K", "score": 50},
      {"student": "L", "score": 78},
      {"student": "M", "score": 66},
      {"student": "N", "score": 30},
      {"student": "O", "score": 97},
      {"student": "P", "score": 75},
      {"student": "Q", "score": 24},
      {"student": "R", "score": 42},
      {"student": "S", "score": 76},
      {"student": "T", "score": 78},
      {"student": "U", "score": 21},
      {"student": "V", "score": 46}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "score", "order": "descending"}]
    }
  ],
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.rank <= 3"}],
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "score", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {
          "field": "student",
          "type": "nominal",
          "sort": {"field": "score", "op": "average", "order": "descending"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.rank > 19"}],
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "score", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {
          "field": "student",
          "type": "nominal",
          "sort": {"field": "score", "op": "average", "order": "descending"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Similarly, if you wanted a different data source in each subchart, you could specify the `"data"` property in the subcharts.